# Why does Byte.parseByte("80", 16) fail?

Tags: java, hex, byte, radix, numberformatexception

```
System.out.println(Byte.toString( (byte)(1 << 7) ));//print "-128" 
System.out.println(Byte.parseByte("80", 16));//run time exception java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"80" Radix:16
```

Why does the first succeed while the second fails? One might expect that they produce the same output.

Comment: Have you read the javadoc?

Comment: From the JavaDoc : I think the last one applies to you :
An exception of type NumberFormatException is thrown if any of the following situations occurs:

The first argument is null or is a string of length zero.
The radix is either smaller than Character.MIN_RADIX or larger than Character.MAX_RADIX.

Any character of the string is not a digit of the specified radix, except that the first character may be a minus sign '-' ('\u002D') or plus sign '+' ('\u002B') provided that the string is longer than length 1.

The value represented by the string is not a value of type byte.

Comment: Ask your real question. The difference between the statements is obvious. I guess you actually want to know why the first succeeds while the second fails, when one might expect that they produce the same output.

Comment: @erickson what u said is exactly what i want to know , still confused why the second statement fails.

Answer (score 1):

Hexadecimal `0x80` is 128 in decimal. Bytes can only hold values from -128 to 127, inclusive. So, when you try to parse a value of 128, it fails because that value can't be represented as a `byte`.

If you want to parse a negative value, you need to include a negative sign:

```
System.out.println(Byte.parseByte("-80", 16)); /* Prints -128 */
```

When performing a [narrowing conversion,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) for example, from `int` to `byte` as in this example, information about the overall magnitude of a value can be lost. Casting an `int` value to `byte` simply discards all but the lowest 8 bits, so casting `int` 128 to `byte` yields `-128`.

Answer (score 0):

The first operator is a binary shift. `-128` represents `0b10000000` in binary code. The `1` shifted seven times to the left.

In the second statement, the radix you're using is for `hex` numbers as you can see in [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/byte_parsebyte_radix.htm)'s example. If you change your statement to `System.out.println(Byte.parseByte("80", 10));`, you won't get the exception.

Hope this explanations was of help.