# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"8C" Radix:16 while converting from String to byte[]

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, hex

Getting the following error from following code. What I am trying to achieve is printing a series of hex code to a file as bytes itself. How do I fix it, So that I can print 8C in the file

```java
public static void process() {
    System.out.println("File to print");
    String hexString = "418C";
    try {
        byte value[] = getByte(hexString);
        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
            outputStream.write(value);
        }
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    
private static byte[] getByte(String str) {
    byte[] val = new byte[str.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
        int index = i * 2;
        byte byt = Byte.parseByte(str.substring(index, index + 2), 16);
        val[i] = byt;
    }
    return val;
}
```

Exception

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"8C" Radix:16
    at java.base/java.lang.Byte.parseByte(Byte.java:154)
```

Based on the following link, I changed to Character.MAX_RADIX, but getting another error.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/byte_parsebyte_radix.htm

The following link was helpful
[Why does Byte.parseByte("80", 16) fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348699/why-does-byte-parsebyte80-16-fail)

Comment: From your last link, `8C` is 140, which is out of range of a byte ( -128 to 127).

Comment: Can you please suggest what should be done?

Comment: Maybe have a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6658409/5612858

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Byte.parseByte(str, 16)` expects signed input. You can write `Byte.parseByte("-1", 16)`, for example, because `-1` fits into Java `byte` type, but not `Byte.parseByte("80", 16)`, because `128` does not fit into Java `byte` type.

You can replace `Byte.parseByte(str.substring(index, index + 2), 16)` with `(byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(index, index + 2), 16)` and it'll work fine.

If you're using Java 17, you can use `java.util.HexFormat.of().parseHex(hexString)` instead of `getByte(hexString)`.

Comment: I am using OpenJDK 11, So I cannot use the second option. First one worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a int to convert and truncate it down to 8 bit length. Look at the two lines in getByte which do the convertion.

```
public class Temp {

    public static void process() {
        System.out.println("File to print");
        String hexString = "418C";
            byte value[] = getByte(hexString);

            for(byte v: value) {
                
                System.out.printf("v: %2x\t", v);
            }
    }

    private static byte[] getByte(String str) {
        byte[] val = new byte[str.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
            int index = i * 2;
            
            int byt = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(index, index + 2), 16);
            val[i] = (byte) (byt & 0xff);

        }
        return val;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        process();
    }
}
```

The output is

```
File to print
v: 41   v: 8c
```